# Load hardware specific keyboard config automatically

Tags: keyboard-layout, systemd, udev, xkb

I have a special keyboard, with which I want to write with a configuration that is not the same as when writing with another keyboard (e.g. the laptop's keyboard). I want to keep both configurations active at the same time.

I already have an `xkbcomp` command, with associated `conf` file, which I can run and get the result I want.

BUT, I need to run the command manually (it's in a script, but I need to run the script manually).

### At login

I could run the script automatically at login, but the keyboard might be disconnected at that time. `xkbcomp` needs a `device_id` (`-i`) to keep the config specific to that device (I fetch that with `xinput`). This requires the keyboard to be connected. Furthermore, connecting the keyboard later in that session (for example by connecting to a docking station) wouldn't work.

### udev

So I implemented a udev rule. Every time the keyboard connects, be it at start-up, or docking, or physically connecting USB, the udev rule should fire a oneshot systemd service and load the config.

The problem is that udev and systemd service all run as root. The `xkbcomp` command I use requires a `DISPLAY`, and root does not have that. The service should run the command for all `DISPLAY` in use on that machine (right? All but root, maybe?).

I found [some way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117083/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-active-x-sessions-and-owners-of-them) to get all `DISPLAYS` on a machine, but the whole thing is starting to get out of hands. There must be a simpler way.

How would you see that input on that keyboard always uses that config? Whatever if it was connected at login or not?